# rtf to html list

Tags: php, html, vba, ms-word

A brief bit of background, I have a lot of notes, I typed 15 years ago in wpd format, about 10 years ago, I converted them to rtf format, now I would like to convert them to html. All the php examples, I've looked at use very basic html. The way I'd like to do it will involves nested lists.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47490038/ech.rtf

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/47490038/notes/index.html

So far I've used the macro below, to go from rtf to txt, but now the php part is beyond me, some of it can be done by counting the tabs or spaces at the start of each line, see the url above for the desired output. I can add the additional styling later.

I'm open to suggestions on how to do this, even if it's a language I'm not familiar with. Even the macro, I'm not really happy with, I'd like to be able to select a folder or a file outside of word, even maybe something with drag & drop considering I'm have 100's of these to convert.

```
            Sub ChangeDocsToTxtOrRTFOrHTML()
            'with export to PDF in Word 2007
                    Dim fs As Object
                    Dim oFolder As Object
                    Dim tFolder As Object
                    Dim oFile As Object
                    Dim strDocName As String
                    Dim intPos As Integer
                    Dim locFolder As String
                    Dim fileType As String
                    On Error Resume Next
                    locFolder = InputBox("Enter the folder path to RTFs", "File Conversion", "C:\myDocs")
                    Select Case Application.Version
                            Case Is < 12
                                    Do
                                            fileType = UCase(InputBox("Change DOC to TXT, RTF, HTML", "File Conversion", "TXT"))
                                    Loop Until (fileType = "TXT" Or fileType = "RTF" Or fileType = "HTML")
                            Case Is >= 12
                                    Do
                                            fileType = UCase(InputBox("Change DOC to TXT, RTF, HTML or PDF(2007+ only)", "File Conversion", "TXT"))
                                    Loop Until (fileType = "TXT" Or fileType = "RTF" Or fileType = "HTML" Or fileType = "PDF")
                    End Select
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                    Set oFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder)
                    Set tFolder = fs.CreateFolder(locFolder & "Converted")
                    Set tFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder & "Converted")
                    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
                            Dim d As Document
                            Set d = Application.Documents.Open(oFile.Path)
                            strDocName = ActiveDocument.Name
                            intPos = InStrRev(strDocName, ".")
                            strDocName = Left(strDocName, intPos - 1)
                            ChangeFileOpenDirectory tFolder
                            Select Case fileType
                            Case Is = "TXT"
                                    strDocName = strDocName & ".txt"
                                    ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatText
                            Case Is = "RTF"
                                    strDocName = strDocName & ".rtf"
                                    ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatRTF
                            Case Is = "HTML"
                                    strDocName = strDocName & ".html"
                                    ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatFilteredHTML
                            Case Is = "PDF"
                                    strDocName = strDocName & ".pdf"

                                    ' *** Word 2007 users - remove the apostrophe at the start of the next line ***
                                    'ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=strDocName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF

                            End Select
                            d.Close
                            ChangeFileOpenDirectory oFolder
                    Next oFile
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            End Sub
```

I realise I'm asking a lot, any guidance, suggestions, help, code will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're trying to get to HTML from RTF, why are you converting them to TXT and losing any/all formatting? Have you googled "RTF to HTML converter"? Looks like there is no shortage of tools out there. Also if I'm not mistaken RTF and HTML share a lot in common as far as markup.

Comment: The rtf formatting contributes nothing to the nest list layout and css styling. Looks can be deceiving, have actually tried any of the google solutions for "RTF to HTML converter"? Are any able to generate nested lists?

Comment: Sorry for being too simplistic but why not just save them as html from Word?  You could even create a batch process to do it.  Another option is to import them into Excel from the txt files (it allows you to set how the data is imported) and then you can import that into a database where you could then do what you want with it via PHP or whatever.  You also might want to consider going to XML instead of HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your source documents are in RTF but they do not use any RTF-based nesting.  Is that right?  For example, a 'level 2' bullet differs from a 'level 1' bullet not because of anything in the RTF but because someone added a few more spaces?

Looking in the file for example I see a lot of \par markers but nothing indicating nesting.  So you have a \par\ul block (for example in 'the primitive church') and then got straight onto the subsection A.1 without anything more than a tab-and-a-prayer (so to speak!)

Given that, you can't rely too much on the RTF.  I suggestion would be to rip out all RTF markup, leaving a doc whose layout is defined only by the use of spaces and tabs.  Then, process each line (Perl is good for this) and work out from the number of spaces and use of leading combinations like  if a new list is starting.  And insert tags accordingly.

It'll be ugly, but that's the price for bad markup.